# Requesting data from Freebase API

Tags: .net, json, google-api, freebase

I need help with returning data from the Freebase API, using the Google APIs .NET library - the documentation for the library is practically non-existent, which is making life pretty difficult.

Based on how I'm using the YouTube library, I've come up with this:

```
string freebaseApiKey = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FreeBaseApiKey"];
FreebaseService fbs = new FreebaseService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
{
    ApiKey = freebaseApiKey        
});

FreebaseService.SearchRequest req = new FreebaseService.SearchRequest(fbs);
req.Query = "{'*':null,'name':'Johnny Cash','type':'/music/artist'}";   

var resp = req.Execute();
```

The `resp` value is a JSON string, but the result is empty :

```
{"status":"200 OK","result":[],"cost":3,"hits":0}
```

Anyone have any advice for me?

Answer (score 3):

If you use a fringe technology you make it that much harder for people to help.  Having said that, what does you query serialize as on the wire?

I'd add array brackets around the outside and replace *:null with *:[{}] but I don't see anything fatal in your query and it works when I use the moral equivalent in the query dashboard.

Here's a [working query](https://www.freebase.com/query?lang=/lang/en&q=%5B%7B%22%2a%22%3a%5B%7B%7D%5D,%22name%22%3a%22Johnny%20Cash%22,%22type%22%3a%22/music/artist%22%7D%5D) that you can translate into the language of your choice -- Python, Java, Ruby -- hell, even PHP or Perl

Comment: Thanks Tom - had a change of heart and am using simple WebClient() calls instead. Surprised at the absolute lack of documentation around the API (Google's, not Freebase), given the depth available for most of the other services